# how to show custom error in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have `MenuBundle` and I want to show my custom error in sonata admin.

Admin : `MenuAdmin.php`

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validate( ErrorElement $errorElement, $object ) {
    //
    if ( $object->getEnabled() == false && $object->getMenuType() == 'header' ) {
        $custom_error = 'Header menu cannot be disabled, please mark enabled to checked.';
        $errorElement->with( 'enabled' )->addViolation( $custom_error )->end();
    }
}
```

`FormMapper in admin`:

```
protected function configureFormFields( FormMapper $formMapper ) {
        $formMapper
            ->add( 'title' )
            ->add( 'menuType', 'choice', array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    'header'        => 'Header',
                    'footer_left'   => 'Footer Left',
                    'footer_right'  => 'Footer Right',
                    'footer_bottom' => 'Footer Bottom'
                ),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ) )
            ->add( 'enabled' );
    }
```

> Validation is working fine but custom error is not appearing.

[image: validation in admin]

Comment: The error is already detected that's why the checkbox is set to red color, if you focus with your mouse in Enabled label is it showing your the error ? can you see with the profiler is there any other errors?

Comment: yeah custom error is shown on mouseover but i want to set error in place of red bar. but there is no any other error with profilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution # 1 :  with [ErrorElement](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/conditional_validation.html)**.

simply use **`error_bubbling => true`** on field.

> Note for solution # 1: Don't forget to add below `use` validator service in admin.
>
> **use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;**

**Solution # 2: With [Sonata - FLASH MESSAGES](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/flash_messages.html)**

I have done it by using [Sonata - FLASH MESSAGES](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/flash_messages.html)

```
$formMapper->add( 'enabled', null, array(
                'error_bubbling' => true
            ) );
```

**MenuAdmin**

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate( ErrorElement $errorElement, $object ) {
        //
        if ( $object->getEnabled() == false && $object->getMenuType() == 'header' ) {
            $error = 'Header menu cannot be disabled, please mark enabled to checked.';
            $errorElement->with( 'enabled' )->addViolation($error)->end();
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add( "menu_type_check", $error );
        }

    }
```

**YML**

> Path : YourBundle\Resources\config\admin.yml

```
sonata_core:
    flashmessage:
        error:
            #css_class: error_msg # optionally, a CSS class can be defined
            types:
                - { type: menu_type_check, domain: YourBundle }
```